# Groovy/Grails: Get key:value pairs satisfying a regexp

Tags: groovy

I have a map and would like to get all key:value pairs where the key matches a regular expression. I have a solution where I grep for the keySet() first them loop through and find. But there must a simpler solution (or I'm hoping).

Ex:

```
def qmap = [name: "hair", style: 'straight', color_1: 'brown', color_2: 'blonde', color_3: 'black']
```

I would like to get a submap with just the colors.

```
def colors = [color_1: 'brown', color_2: 'blonde', color_3: 'black']
```

I can get the keys by using .grep, but this just gives me the keys and I need to loop through to get the values.

```
def colorKeys = qmap.keySet().grep(~/^color.*/)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
qmap.subMap( colorKeys )
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple. Just do:

```
qmap.findAll{ k,v -> k.matches(~/^color.*/) }
```